# Prepare a USB-stick for bootable linux. Need to?

Tags: linux, usb, iso

I have put `linuxmint-20-xfce-64bit.iso` (with `dd`) on a FAT32,64G USB drive. When I checked it afterwards with `gparted`, it doesn't report any information about the partition, just a simple line with the ISO name. Is this optimal? Is it the best way to use the USB? I think the USB drive is working rather slow.

I have worked with Raspberry Pi and the SD-card has several partitions (boot, root, swap etc). Some partitions are formatted with FAT32, and some of them with ext4. Shouldn't my bootable USB drive be like that? Why doesn't  the ISO result in a USB drive with several partitions with correct formatting?

Please, be patient. I have not worked with Linux so much yet. I'm still in elementary school.

Comment: Regarding how to create a USB drive with partitioning, you can check: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44466/how-do-i-create-a-usb-image-with-a-partition-table

Comment: If you want a general description of cloning and extraction from an iso file to a USB drive, see [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb). If you want details, see [this link](https://www.cnblogs.com/hustdc/p/7051133.html) or search the internet for more details. Thomas Schmitt can describe the boot sector in iso files on a very detailed level.

Comment: If a 64GB flash drive, you have room for a full install of Ubuntu and multiple ISO. You then can use grub2's loopmount to boot ISO. And you still have some room for some backup data. ISO boot & link to examples
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
more examples
https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/27203177bdef15fbb70c

Comment: Thanks. I will check the links. I'm not giving up.  BTW, this USB that I have, I bought it  from US. It had XtraPC on it. However, I wanted another distro. So....I took the decision to dd an iso and here I am. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISO file is a block-by-block image of what would be on a bootable optical disk (CD-ROM, DVD, etc.).  These disks are in ISO9660 format (that's why the image file is a ".ISO" file) rather than FAT32, ext4, or any of the other filesystem types you may be familiar with, and they don't have partitions in the way you are thinking of (ISO9660 doesn't even have a partition table).  If you just `dd` the ISO image on to your USB flash drive, whatever partitioning you formatted the USB flash drive with originally will be gone, because this operation overwrites the partition table.  When you boot your system from a USB flash drive, it doesn't care about partition tables or anything like that - it just loads the boot block from the flash drive (just as it would do with any other drive you are booting from) and runs whatever code it finds there.  It is up to the boot code to decide what to do next, and how to interpret whatever is on the flash drive.  When you boot from a USB flash drive that you've written an ISO image to using `dd` or similar, the system literally treats it as if it's booting from an optical drive - just the same as if you had burned the ISO image on to a writable CD-ROM or DVD disk, and booted from that instead.

If you are using USB 2.0 flash drives, then that is going to be sort of slow, no matter what else you do.  The type of filesystem on the flash drive doesn't change this.  If you use a USB 3.x flash drive, on a system with USB 3.x interfaces, access will be much faster.  If you use a USB 3.x flash drive on a system that only has USB 2.0 interfaces, you're only going to get USB 2.0 speed regardless of what kind of flash drive you use.

Comment: Aha! I get it! So, if I make the USB-stick with a boot partition, this ISO I have are NOT sutiable in a ext4 partition that should contain linux OS. Stupid me. However, I thought the ISO made a USB with several partitions. Not a CD. Thanx!

Comment: That is correct.  When you `dd` a boot image to an SD card for your Raspberry Pi, that is not an ISO image, it is (essentially) a hard disk image - complete with a partition table, separate partitions, etc.  An ISO image is not the same thing.

Comment: Many Linux distributions use hybrid ISOs, they include an EFI partition inside the image.  Pure ISO9660 images may not be bootable from USB drives but actually require either a CD/DVD or using a tool that creates a functioning EFI (and/or MBR) bootloader.

Comment: It's only the legacy BIOS boot that relies on boot sector. The modern (U)EFI actually uses partitions, in particular the FAT-formatted EFI System Partition and `\EFI\BOOTX64.EFI` on it in case of AMD64 systems.

Comment: I done it with a xubuntu iso live. I made the second USB-stick to start xubuntu (used Linux usb start whatever-the-name-is) and then I put my empty (ext4 formatted) USB-stick in another USB-port. I clicked "Install xubuntu" and chose "alternative install". All partitions came up. I chose the empty USB-stick dev. Then I made a partition with mounting pos '/'.
It will boot in two tested Laptops. The newest (got it this week) would not boot. Why? Don't know - yet.